# Why is calcium stearate (soap scum) insoluble in water while potassium/sodium stearate are soluble in water?

Tags: water, ions, polarity

So, potassium and sodium containing soaps work because they have a polar end and a non-polar structure for the rest of the molecule - they can thus be dissolved in polar and non-polar solvents. This is why they're used for cleaning, as they can basically clean off anything non-polar like oil while still lathering/rinsing off with water.

Now, my question is, what changes when 'hard soap' is formed? Here, when the stearate ion of soap is released in hard water, an ion of magnesium/calcium bonds with it forming 'hard soap'. The thing I don't get is why it is now insoluble in water. What's changed?

Based on electronegativity values, there's very little difference between atoms of potassium, sodium and calcium/magnesium, not enough to change the polarity. The ion from the hard water bonds with an oxygen atom, and the electronegativity difference between an atom of calcium/magnesium and an atom of oxygen is still large enough for it to be polar at the same end as it was with sodium/potassium.

What's going on?

Comment: 'Hard soap' isn't totally insoluble in water, it is just less soluble that the sodium or potassium forms. In making lye soap the ancient process was in fact to "salt" out the soap by adding salts (sodium chloride usually...).

Comment: @MaxW That makes sense, but why exactly is it it so much less soluble than the sodium/potassium forms? The electronegativity change doesn't account for it whatsoever, is there another reason?

Comment: The "hand waving" reason - With a soap that has a monovalent anion, a cation with a +1 charge still has a "polar" end for the "molecule." With a divalent cation the two polar ends are both attracted to the cation, thus the polar part is in the center of large molecule with no polar end.